# Addressing array by index returns array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I am going through an array and replacing a string according to what is in the array. When i try to debug, and print the array, instead if printing one item at a time, the console just prints out the whole array. Is it just a quirk of the google chrome console or am I doing something wrong?

The `from` array is filled in with Chrome's `storage.sync` function

**Code**

This is my looping function, really simple

```
from.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item)
    textToChange = textToChange.replace(item[index], to[index][index])
})
```

**Expected output**

```
a
c
```

**Real output**

```
["a", "c"]
```

Comment: Why are you using the index of `from` as an index into `item` and `to`?

Comment: Post the value of `from`. It looks like it's a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar from and to are of the same length, and items in each of them correspond to each other, that is why im using the same index. What i can also assume is that item is the item the loop is working with, but since it prints as an array i also take an index from it

Comment: Don't tell, show. Post sample values of `from` and `to`. It looks like `from` is `[["a", "c"]]` but you seem to expect it to be `["a", "c"]`.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you use `item[index]` instead of just `item` or `from[index]` in the `replace()` call.

Comment: @Barmar when i print the from array I get `Array(2) 0:"a" 1:"c"`, and i decided to use `item[index]` because it was an array on log

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fymaxewp/2/

Comment: The `replace` call should be `textToChange.replace(item, to[index])`. But that's unrelated to the `console.log()` output.

Comment: @Barmar could it be because there is an object that contains the array, which gets pushed onto from? Say I have `var result - {from:["a", "c"]}` and then I do `from.push(reuslt.from)`

Comment: Yes, that would do it. You should do `from = from.concat(result.from)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211180/discussion-between-barmar-and-dudeking412).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @Barmar

The problem was that I wasn't pushing the contents of an object on the array, but rather the object itself, creating a two-dimensional array.

I did

```
from.push(result.from)
```

I had to do

```
from = from.concat(result.from)
```